# Enumerate with \noindent

Tags: macros, environments, indentation, enumerate

I am creating a custom macro for enumerated lists, but with this attempt, I haven't been able to eliminate the indentation of the item numbers. Every time I use `\myitemize`, the lists still indents.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
\newenvironment{myitemize}
{ \noindent\begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}     }
{ \end{enumerate}                  }
```

Answer (score 7):

For jobs like this, use `enumitem` that provides flexible options. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myitemize}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[myitemize]{label*=\arabic*.,nosep,leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
Here is some text
\begin{myitemize}
  \item some text
  \item some text
\end{myitemize}
And again some more...
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the labels for second level by

```
\setlist[myitemize,2]{label=\alph*),nosep,leftmargin=*}
```

If `label*` is used instead of `label`, we will get `1.a)`, `1.b)` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myitemize}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[myitemize]{label*=\arabic*.,nosep,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[myitemize,2]{label=\alph*),nosep,leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
Here is some text
\begin{myitemize}
  \item some text
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item some text
  \item some text
\end{myitemize}
  \item some text
\end{myitemize}
And again some more...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) Why didn't my macro work? It seems like a simple solution. (2) What do all those things in your commands do ? the 10, \arabic*, nosep, leftmargin=*...

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything: You didn't change `leftmargin` in your macro. To change it you need to do more work. So it didn't work. Second, `\arabic*` is the label, `nosep` means all those spaces (like itemsep, parsep...) are `0pt` and `leftmargin=*` means start from the left most end. See `enumitem` manual for these details.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything: BTW, Your macro is not the simple solution, but my method is :)

Comment: How might I change this macro so that embedding a `myitemize` list within a `myitemize` list results in getting a list of, say,  2. a), b), c), etc.?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Please see the update.