# Making my own list with custom numbering

Tags: lists, environments, enumitem

I am making my own list,  similar to enumerate. I want numbering to be aligned to the right, so everything looks like this:

```
 1. Text
    Text
11. Text
    Text
```

I also want to sometimes put a special symbol after automatically put number like (this doen't work, but I hope the idea is clear):

```
\item la-la-la
\item[*] difficult la-la-la
```

So I would like the document to look like:

```
 1. la-la-la
2*. difficult la-la-la
```

The problem is that it looks like:

```
 1. la-la-la
 *. difficult la-la-la
```

so the "2" is gone.

Is there any solution?

My code so far (I am using LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=1.25in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{skull}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newcounter{qcounter}
\newcommand{\TTT}[1]{#1:}

\newenvironment{questions}{
    \begin{list}{ 
        \hfill\bfseries\upshape\arabic{qcounter}.
    }{
        \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\TTT}%
        \usecounter{qcounter}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{2em}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{3em}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1em}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{3pt}
        \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
    } 
}{    
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{questions}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261582/enumerate-with-noindent

Comment: @Yorgos I am not sure I get to the point

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. You want your nested enumerate environment to start with 1*? (for instance) or you want to have some items like 1,2,3*,4,.....? From what i know, you can use `enumitem` package in order to modify your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you do not want to nest these environments, you can define a new enumerate-like environment using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package with the command:

```
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
```

This defines a `questions` environment that behaves like an `enumerate` environment and has `1` level of nesting (to allow nesting change `{1}` to give the required nesting level but you will also have to modify `\fakeitem` below). You can set the "properties" of your environment using the command:

```
\setlist[questions]{
   label=\arabic*.,   % label format
   leftmargin=*,      % indent labels
   before=\let\item\fakeitem,
}
```

The first two lines I have explained with comments. The `before=` command redefines the `\item` command to be `\fakeitem` *only* inside this environment. The idea is that we hijack `\item` to make it do what you want. The label counter for this environment is `questionsi` so we need `\fakeitem` to accept an optional argument, which it should add to the label, and we need to manually increment the counter:

```
\newcommand\fakeitem[1][\relax]{% argument defaults to \relax
   \refstepcounter{questionsi}%  increment label counter
   \realitem[\arabic{questionsi}#1.]}
}
```

Here `\realitem` is the original `\item` command.

Putting this together gives what you want:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\let\realitem\item% save a copy of the \item command
\newcommand\fakeitem[1][\relax]{% argument defaults to \relax=do nothing
   \refstepcounter{questionsi}
   \realitem[\arabic{questionsi}#1.]% make label <questioni>#1.
}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}% define a new enumerate environment
\setlist[questions]{% define properties of questions
   label=\arabic*., % label format
   leftmargin=*,    % indent labels
   before=\let\item\fakeitem, % change the \item command
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for MWe only

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}
       \item la-la-la
       \item[*] difficult la-la-la
       \item[$\dag$] \lipsum[1]
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Btw, there is another nice feature of using [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem): if you would like all of the `questions` environments to use the same numbering then all you have to do is add `resume` to the `\setlist` command:

```
\setlist[questions]{
   label=\arabic*.,   % label format
   leftmargin=*,      % indent labels
   before=\let\item\fakeitem,
   resume             % use continuous numbering for the questions environments
}
```

Comment: I am now working to set the vertical spacing between items. I use `itemsep=3pt`. But it is bigger than 3pt, comparing to other part of the document, where the vertical space is made manually. What can be the  solution here?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann The [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) manual is usually pretty good but it is a little vague on this point. The vertical spacing between items is controlled by `itemsep` *and* `parsep`. Adding `itemsep=0pt` and `parsep=3pt` to the `\setlist` command will probably give you want you want: this should give you `3pt` separation between items and between paragraphs in items. The alternative is `itemsep=3pt` and `parsep=0pt` which will give `3pt` between items and `0pt` between paragraphs.