# Using enumitem, how can I remove the label and the indent from an individual item in a list?

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I am creating a list in LaTeX using the enumitem package, and having trouble setting the alignment of one item in the list. For that one item, I want to remove the label *and* decrease the indent so that item is aligned with the labels of the previous items.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
  \item Item 4
  \item[] Item 5
\end{enumerate}
```

Which looks like this:

```
1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3
4. Item 4
   Item 5
```

But what I want is this:

```
1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3
4. Item 4
Item 5
```

Making a new paragraph doesn't work because LaTeX automatically creates space after the list and Item 5 needs to be part of the list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could always use `\item[]\hspace*{-whatever your indent is} Item 5` but how is the reader to to know that's item 5?  it would be better markup to just end the list after 4, and arrange that it does not add vertical space

Answer (score 1):

Changing your syntax slightly (just to add more functionality), you can use `\item*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\let\endoldenumerate\endenumerate
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{enumerate}{O{}}
  {\begin{oldenumerate}[#1]
     \let\olditem\item
     \RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{s}{%
       \IfBooleanTF{##1}
         {\olditem[]\hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelindent-\labelwidth-\labelsep}\ignorespaces}
         {\olditem}}
     }
  {\end{oldenumerate}}

\begin{document}

Some reference text.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
  \item Item 4
  \item[] Item 5
\end{enumerate}

Some reference text.

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
  \item Item 4
  \item* Item 5
\end{enumerate}

Some reference text.

\end{document}
```

The above redefinition of the `enumerate` environment keeps the optional argument functionality provided by [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) while changing the way `\item` functions; it adds a starred `\item*` version. This `*`-version sets a regular `\item[]` and backspaces to the margin.

Comment: I think the O.P. wants to backspace to the left side of the labels (which implies using the key `align=left`, or `wide`).

Comment: Rather than redefining the `enumerate` environment you can, instead, add `before=\let\olditem\newitem`  to the environment, where `\newitem` is the `*`-accepting item command. See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342934/making-my-own-list-with-custom-numbering/342948#342948