# inline itemize list with no label or label indentation

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I found out about inline lists with the enumitem package and it works exactly how I wanted except for the fact that there is some leading spacing before each item. I tried reading through the [manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) and I honestly couldn't make sense of the various different spacing parameters, or if any of them have any effect. I suspect it's some edge case with the list being inline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newlist{commalist}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[commalist]{label={},itemjoin={{·}}}

\begin{document}

First Line

\begin{commalist}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
\end{commalist}

Second Line

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

I saw [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342934/making-my-own-list-with-custom-numbering/342948#342948) which gave me the idea for redefining the `\item` command within the list environment, but I couldn't quite get it to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\let\realitem\item
\newcommand{\mynewitem}{%
\realitem\hspace*{-\labelsep}\ignorespaces%
}

\newlist{commalist}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[commalist]{before={\let\item\mynewitem},label={},itemjoin={{·}}}

\begin{document}

First Line

{%
\setlength\parskip{0pt}%
\begin{commalist}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
\end{commalist}}

Second Line

\end{document}
```

[image: attempt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops! The answer is simply to set `afterlabel={}` since by default it is set to `\nobreakspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newlist{commalist}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[commalist]{label={},itemjoin={{·}},afterlabel={}}

\begin{document}

First Line

\begin{commalist}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
\end{commalist}

Second Line

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full sentence with afterspace={} at the right place in your MWE.

Comment: Good idea, edited.